# Is difference in relative data (compositional data) is still a a compositional data?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, compositional-data

The table below shows an example of relative data collected in two different time steps:

[image: Original data]

Y is an independent variable that is not part of the composition.
The goal is to study the regression between the temporal differences between parts (∆C1, ∆C2 and ∆C3) and ∆Y (Table below).

[image: Temporal difference of compositional data]

To my understanding, the original data in the first table is relative, positive, and sums to 100, so it's better to use compositional statistics. For example, if we want to make a regression between C1,C2 and C3 and Y in one time steps we should use compositional regression. However, the temporal difference in relative variables adds to zero, and it has negative/zero numbers. Considering the difference data is produced from compositional data, to make a regression (second table) should we use standard or compositional methods?

Comment: This question is a little confusing because the sums aren't all correct.  If they were, the row sums in the bottom table should all be zero. This raises the issue of whether you even have true compositional data.

Comment: Thanks, I just made these numbers up and there were some typos in them. I just corrected the tables. Also, yes the sum of the rows in the second table is zero. I edited the question accordingly.